# resizableSnapshotViewFromRect does not resize views within the hierarchy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am making an application that displays a bunch of items in a scrollview with different sections having their own items. One feature is to expand each item so it will appear fullscreen, for this effect I use `resizableSnapshotViewFromRect` to create a snapshot of the view in it's fullscreen dimensions and then scale it down inside the scrollview.

The problem is that for the first displayed section, these views do not get a snapshot of their fullscreen dimensions but rather their downscaled dimensions. For the other sections that do not have their views in the hierarchy the snapshots look fine once you change section so you can view them. I had initially solved this by making a snapshot and then adding the views to the hierarchy in a `dispatch_async` call, which postponed the view being added after the snapshot finished.

Now I have a case where an image inside the original view for the snapshot might get updated, and thus I'd like to regenerate the snapshot but this fails of course and I have no idea what I should do. In my searchings I haven't found anyone with the same problems so maybe the problem is something else, I don't know, but my findings so far point to the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off Auto Layout.

Or

Use Constraints as IBOutlets

Comment: Could you give a bit more explaination about you suggest ?

Comment: Of course. In your storyboard go to file inspector (witch is the first icon) on the Utilities Panel on the right) and uncheck Use Auto Layout.